# Git post-receive restart forever(node.js)?

Tags: node.js, git, githooks, forever

I am using git on my server as a remote repo, inside post-receive I define my work-tree where the files are hosted and my git-dir.

I am using node.js with forever on this app and in order for most changes to take effect I need to run `forever restart server.js`. It's a pain to have to login via ssh and cd to the directory and manually do it.

So I was thinking is it possible to issue a command within the post-receive, like `forever restart server.js`?

**Here is my post-receive file**

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/var/www/example/public_html --git-dir=/var/repo/examp$
forever restart ../../../www/example/public_html/server.js
```

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/745762.

Comment: So basically just issue the command? I cant restart forever outside of where the script is located, I mean do I start the script like `forever restart ../../../www/example/server.js`

Answer (score 2):

I use the absolute path to my node server file with the forever restart command.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Checking out files"

git --work-tree=/path/to/node/server --git-    dir=/path/to/site.git checkout -f

# If app-server.js is running, restart--otherwise start
forever restart /path/to/node/server/app-server.js
```

EDIT: As prescribed by Norman, this should be in your .git/hooks directory on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not define the post-receive hook inside `.git/hooks` in your server. I think you can add a bash command in there to restart forever.

Comment: Well I tried manually restarting it in the root directory on the command line like this `forever restart var/www/example/server.js` and it said no forever processes started, so I assumed running that from post-receive would result the same. I don't know what I need to do to run it from another path.

Comment: Have you tried it with `sudo forever ...` ? We have the same problem on our EC2 servers. Forever does not work without sudo.

Comment: I know its not ideal to be logged in as root, but I am indeed logged in as root.

Comment: Please do a `forever list` first to make sure if any forever process is running so that forever can restart it.

Comment: I have updated with my post-receive file, the forever processes are running.

Comment: Solved it then I guess :) What was the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Super late reply.

In the package.json, make sure forever is in the deps and add a start and stop script.

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "forever start index.js",
  "stop": "forever stop index.js"
}
```

And inside your hook, just do:

```
npm run stop
npm install
npm run start
```

Easier way to deploy node app through git is to use this kind of tools:
[Piriku](https://www.npmjs.com/package/piriku)